# Node not recognizing correct default version

Tags: node.js, nvm

I have been unable to change, or at least get node to recognize my default node version as `v20.8.1`. I installed the version and ran `nvm list` to confirm that it was installed, and it's there. I also ran the command `nvm alias default 20.8.1` and did not receive any errors. I have also tried to run `nvm use default` and `nvm use 20.8.1`, which shows `v20.8.1`. In the list of versions, `v20.8.1` is identified as the default version, however, when I run `node -v`, it is showing that my version is `v19.6.0`. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

```
~ nvm alias default 20.8.1
default -> 20.8.1 (-> v20.8.1)
```

—

```
~ nvm list
        v8.12.0
       v10.15.3
       v12.11.0
        v16.0.0
        v16.4.1
       v16.10.0
       v16.11.1
       v16.13.0
        v17.0.1
        v17.1.0
        v18.0.0
       v18.12.0
       v18.12.1
        v19.6.0
        v20.0.0
        v20.1.0
        v20.5.0
        v20.8.1
->       system
default -> 20.8.1 (-> v20.8.1)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v20.8.1) (default)
stable -> 20.8 (-> v20.8.1) (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.2 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.18.2 (-> N/A)
```

—

```
~ nvm use default
Now using node v20.8.1 (npm v9.9.0)
```

—

```
~ nvm use 20.8.1
Now using node v20.8.1 (npm v9.9.0)
```

—

```
~ node -v
v19.6.0
```

Comment: Is everything shimmed correctly? Your shell unit script is correct?

Comment: Yup—never had this problem before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have installed nodejs before.

Check with the following cmd:
`which node`

If the returned result is not in the .nvm folder, uninstall it

Comment: That command returns /opt/homebrew/bin/node

Comment: @techmeowt That means it’s not shimmed correctly and/or your brew path is before the shims. Look at your path and init script(s).

Comment: You can follow this article: https://tecadmin.net/install-nvm-macos-with-homebrew